# Conflict with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I’m using php echo to call meta data within the head of several php files. All files include the unique meta file using this code:

```
<?php
include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/meta.php";
?>
```

Here is what the unique meta file looks like:

```
<?php

if (preg_match("@contact@", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
$meta=<<<EOF
<title>FR Contact title</title>
<meta name="description" content="FR Contact description">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ch/contact" hreflang="fr-CH" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ch/de/contact" hreflang="de-CH" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ch/it/contact" hreflang="it-CH" />
EOF;
}
elseif (preg_match("@de/contact@", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
$meta=<<<EOF
<title>DE Contact title</title>
<meta name="description" content="DE Contact description">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ch/de/contact" hreflang="de-CH" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ch/contact" hreflang="fr-CH" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ch/it/contact" hreflang="it-CH" />
EOF;
}
//echo ">>>>>" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "<<<<";
?>
```

For some unknown reason, I have a conflict when calling similar URL's with **preg_match**, despite the different folder name related to the country: **de/contact** bugs and display the french description.

However, when editing slightly the folder name: **de/kontakt** is working and displays the german description.

Could you please tell me how to avoid this bug ?

Comment: Does the answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your `contact` in the first `preg_match` matches both urls, a regex looks for any occurrence in the whole string. You could swap the order:

```
if (preg_match("@de/contact@", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
...
} else {
serve french
}
```

this way if you get the German match first you stop there. If not you just serve the default french content. (Assuming that's the functionality you want, if not you can put the `if` on that `else` and do the same `preg_match`. You also could put an optional term in the regex for `kontakt`.

```
if (preg_match("@de/(?:contact|kontakt)@", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
```